Error displaying vf page in lwc through iframe
I have a visualforce page which i need to show on a community using lwc. I am using the iframe in lwc to display that.
<iframe id="LWCWithVFPage" src="/apex/testVfpage" width="100%" height="350px"> </iframe>

when I open the community with a user having system admin profile it works and i can see the vf page on the lwc. But when i login as an experience user and view the lwc then the vf page is not displayed and i get an error in console
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () and instead of vf page content i see a log in page.

The community user has access to the vf page as well.
